# How to insert annotation with auto y value

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Is it possible to create annotations without knowledge of `y` value?

I have a chart with series and annotations which I want to show on the chart. But I only have the `x` value and want the annotation to have the same `y` value as the chart has on that `x`.

I tried to find the answer in the documentation, but haven't found it. I'm thinking of somehow fining the `y` value by knowing `x`, and then inserting the annotation at that point.

I created an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-curran-zurqz)

Answer (score 2):

You should add this annotation dynamically inside the load callback inside which you can calculate the annotation position because this function is triggered after the chart has been initialized.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
      let chart = this,
        y;

      chart.series[0].points.forEach((point) => {
        if (point.x === 1572566400000) {
          console.log(point);
          y = point.y;
        }
      });
      chart.addAnnotation({
        shapeOptions: {},
        shapes: [
          {
            src: "https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png",
            type: "image",
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            point: {
              x: 1572566400000,
              y: y,
              xAxis: 0,
              yAxis: 0
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-kalam-9qzf3?file=/src/App.js

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addAnnotation

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: In this case, we loop through series data, but what if the `y` we are looking for is not included in series data? Referencing the demo - we want the `y` where `x` is "2019-11-15". As I see it, we are not able to get `y` this way, or am I wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand - the `x` "2019-11-15" is not included in the data, so there is no point for this x value.

Comment: That's right, perhaps I'm not using annotations right, but the point is, that i have some information and an image, that has the date "2019-11-15" and would like to show it on the chart by the point for that date. It''s not explaining data points from the series but as a complement. I wonder, if there is an API for getting a custom `y` for some `x` or vice versa.

Comment: You can place your annotation wherever you want, take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a8k1vt42/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.point.x as you can find in the API, the coordinates could be: `Units can be either in axis or chart pixel coordinates.`

Comment: This is great, but i need to know somehow, what the `y` value is at `x = 1.5` in your fiddle, to position the annotation on the line. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I think that you should be able to calculate this `y` as the average of the nears points. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bgsfaprk/